# C# application insert in database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm writing a C# application with a SQL Server CE database.

I have this code for insert:

```
this.Validate();
this.documentacionBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.documentacionTableAdapter.Update(baseDatosDataSet.Documentacion);
```

But it does not work. I try this and it works:

```
this.Validate();
this.documentacionBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.documentacionTableAdapter.Insert(....);
```

If a gridview without rows the first one work but is a form not work

Why?

Comment: I don’t  think c# support data binding in compact framework

Comment: Sorry - do you mean **.NET Compact Framework**, or do you mean **SQL Server Compact Edition** as your database? Your original post was unclear in this point....

Comment: Sql Server Server Compact Edition, sdf file in the app directory.